# How to make a shadow between two table views?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, shadow

I have two table view controllers. How can I make shadow like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at CALayer class from CoreAnimation framework. Here is a nice tutorial with examples: http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths

Then you apply the shadow to the right tableview(however, it might be required embedding the tableview in container view)

Comment: +1: CALayer shadow is maybe bit more complex then a trans-png, but it's more flexible in future!

Comment: Totally agree - I was on my iPhone when I suggested the png approach, as I couldn't remember the CALayer code off the top of my head...

Answer (score 0):

The easy way if you don't know about core graphics is to make a gradient png and position/size it to the right of your cell, under everything else.

Comment: I need make this with Core Graphics

Answer (score 0):

In UIBuilder, select the view containing the table.  You may need to play around with the exact level of what you select.  On the far right in the inspectors, is the View Effects inspector.  There you can set a shadow, including the blur radius and offset.  If you just set the shadow without either a blur radius or an offset, you won't see the shadow, since it will be directly behind your table.

[image]

Comment: the question is tagged iphone, so one cannot use IB to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drop shadow easily, using QuartzCore.

Code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

UIView *myView = <your view here>
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGPointMake(5, 5);
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
```

That should do it.

Please note that, when setting the shadowOffset, using positive values will drop to the right and bottom, using negatives will do the opposite.

Comment: you should also set shadowPath when adding shadow this way for performance reasons(try putting a few shadowed objects on the uiscrollview to see how expensive operation that is)

Comment: I agree but for a quick and dirty example, that would work just fine.